# What is the meaning of `use path::{self}`?

Tags: rust, self

I recently read the [following line of code](https://github.com/rust-lang/rust/blob/c90f68224b069f5bb2a80e30e2737e4bb17c1466/src/libstd/collections/hash/map.rs#L17):

```
use fmt::{self, Debug};
```

What does the `self` keyword in the above statement mean?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Using `self` in that context allows you to bind a module plus some of it's child elements into the current scope with a single `use` statement.

Without self:

```
use a::b::{c,d};
// Now you can refer to a::b::c as c and a::b::d as d
// but if you need to refer to a::b as a::b
```

With self:

```
use a::b::{self, c, d};
// Now b refers to a::b as well
```

Comment: could you point why i would need to use both in case of fmt (why it's not 
 enough to write just fmt::Debug).?

Comment: `fmt` contains the struct `Result`. Personally I don't want to overwrite `Result` in my namespace, so I use `fmt::Result`. I.e. `fn fmt(&self, f: Formatter) -> fmt::Result;`. You only need this, if you want to use the module itself.

Comment: @Tim, what role does 'self' play in example provided in the question.? 
 from my understaning, after removing 'self' I will still be able to use 'fmt', since it's introduced erlier into the root scope.

Comment: @GreenTree no, you won't be able to use `fmt`, if you remove `self`

Comment: @Tim https://ideone.com/n4tXWB but why such 'direct' usage in 'goo' 
 allowed, right after mod declaration, without no 'use' statement.?

Comment: @GreenTree You declared the mod `boo` just before. Why accepting an answer if you don't understand it?

Comment: @GreenTree use the [Rust Playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/) instead of [ideone.com](https://ideone.com/) for rust.

Comment: @Tim, because it does answer the question raised. i'm trying to clarify what i'm missing in the example. if `use` allows only absolute paths, 'fmt' should be start of the path, module, right.? so it should be at least declared with `mod fmt` erlier - if so, use fmt::{self} is redeclaration.

Comment: @GreenTree not necessarily earlier, but anywhere, yes.

Comment: @Tim, so why the build does not fail with error (`fmt` reimported here).?

Comment: @GreenTree it does not. The mod is defined somewhere else.

Answer (score 8):

`self` here refers to the module itself, i.e. your line is equivalent to the two lines

```
use fmt::Debug;
use fmt;
```